# React cannot read property '' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

please im having issue rendering dynamic data in my react ProductScreen.js

Note,... the data rendered well in Product.js but same data isnt render in the ProductScreen.js because the ProductScreen.js link is rendered via the "id"

Thanks
App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

//Screens
import  HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import  ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';
import  CartScreen from './screens/CartScreen';

//components
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Backdrop from './components/Backdrop'
import SideDrawer from './components/SideDrawer'
import AddProductScreen from './screens/AddProductScreen';
import data from './data'

function App() {

  const { products } = data;

  const [sideToggle, setSideToggle] = useState(false)

  const [cartItems, setCartItem] = useState([])

  const onAdd = (product) =>{
    const exist = cartItems.find(item => item.id === product.id)
    if (exist) {
      setCartItem(cartItems.map(item => item.id === product.id ? {...exist, qty: exist.qty + 1} : item ))
    } else{
      setCartItem([...cartItems, {...product, qty: 1}])
    }
  }
  const onRemove =(product) =>{

  }

  



  return (

    
    <Router>
      <Navbar countCartItems={cartItems.length} click={() => setSideToggle(true)}/>
      <Backdrop show={sideToggle} click={() => setSideToggle(false)} />
      <SideDrawer show={sideToggle} click={() => setSideToggle(false)} />
      {/* <HomeScreen products={ products } onAdd={ onAdd }/> */}
      {/* <CartScreen onRemove={onRemove} onAdd={onAdd} cartItems={cartItems}/> */}

      {products.map(product => (
        <h1></h1>
      ))}
      
      
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" > <HomeScreen  products={ products } onAdd={ onAdd }/> </Route>
          <Route exact path="/cart" > <CartScreen cartItems={cartItems} onRemove={ onRemove } onAdd={ onAdd }/> 
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/product/:id" > <ProductScreen cartItems={cartItems}  onAdd={ onAdd }/> products={products} </Route>
          
          <Route exact path="/add" component={AddProductScreen} />
        </Switch>
      </main>
     </Router>
  );
}

export default App;


HomeScreen.js
```

import './HomeScreen.css';
import Product from '../components/Product'
import { useEffect } from 'react';

// import data from '../data'
const HomeScreen = ({ onAdd, products }) => {

```
// const { products } = data;
return (
    <div className="homescreen">
        <h1 className="homescreen_title">Latest Products</h1>

        <div className="homescreen_products">
            {products.map(product => (
                <Product key={ product.id } product={ product } onAdd={ onAdd }/>
            )) }
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default HomeScreen

ProductScreen.js

```
import './ProductScreen.css';

const ProductScreen = ({ products }) => {
    return (
        <div className="productscreen">
            <div className="productscreen__left">
                <div className="left__image">
                <img className="small" src={products.image} alt={product.name} />
                </div>
                <div className="left__info">
                    <p className="left__name">{products.name}</p>
                    <p >${products.price}</p>
                    <p >${products.descrption}</p>
                </div>
                
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductScreen
```

Product.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Product = ({ product, onAdd }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <img className="small" src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
            <h3>{product.name}</h3>
            <div>${product.price}</div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={()=> onAdd(product)}> Add To Cart</button>
                <button > <Link to={`/product/${product.id}`}>Features</Link></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Product
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are sending the items to ProductsScreen as **cartItems** `<ProductScreen cartItems = {cartItems} onAdd = {onAdd} />` but you are calling the **product** property that does not exist `const ProductScreen = ({product}) => {}`

Comment: okay, thanks alot... i have passed products to the <ProductScreen products={ products } /> as like this. but inside the ProductScreen.js {products.image} or {products.name} isnt working. please help me out

Comment: it's weird, you can update your code with the new changes please?

Comment: Also, don't forget that your products are an array, so you must access the data through a product[i].name loop. Like it did in HomeScreen `products.map (product =>`